# Scanning a php file for variables

Tags: php, content-management-system

I have a set of templates that contain php variables and logic. I want to find a particular variable, $template, which is an array that is stored at the top of each file. I want to be able to scan, find and then use the variables within this page.

The process doesn't need to be particularly speedy as it's a process that's going to be run to rescan the template for custom fields.

Anyone got any ideas about how this can be achieved?

I cannot simply include it as that will run the logic contained within the php file itself.

Comment: `include('file.php')`. boom. done.

Comment: I cannot simply include it as that will run the logic contained within the php file itself.

Comment: If you don't need it particularly speedy... Go for a redesign which wouldn't require you running a partial script only. Yes, with time & effort your goal can be achieved, but that time & effort is better spent elsewhere.

Comment: Please can you offer an alternative way of making this work?

Comment: If you cannot include the php files you would need to parse the actual text from the file which would usually be much more complicated than rewriting your current code.